# Splitting txt using batch containing "=" on each line

Tags: batch-file, text, split

I'm splitting the file every 6000 lines with the script below but I'm having a problem with it....
Every line of my txt file has the character '=' so when the batch is treating the file, where I have the '=' the line stops and goes to the next one (I don't have the end of each line, anything that follows the = is deleted).

```
FOR %%X IN (*.TXT) do (
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET BFN=%%X
SET LPF=6000
SET SFN=%%X_6000_
)
REM ==============================
SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%

SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum=1

For /F "delims==" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
SET /A LineNum+=1

echo %%l >> %SFN%!FileNum!.%SFX%

if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum+=1
)

)
endlocal
```

Can Someone help me out?

Sample of file:

```
A88A0A1891BAA9=B088A00000003800001==00000038000
A88A0A1B13A0BB=B088A00000089000002==00000890000
A88A0A1A13B830=B088A000000B3800003==00000B38000
A88A0A00331831=B088A00000010A00004==0000010A000
A88A0A10B31B39=B088A00000090A00005==0000090A000
A88A0A19A3AA89=B088A00000089800006==00000898000
A88A0A19AA0318=B088A000000A0100007==00000A01000
A88A0A08911913=B088A00000008800008==00000088000
A88A0A1089A139=B088A00000098300009==00000983000
A88A0A1BB8BBA8=B088A000000AA100010==00000AA1000
A88A0A0A8B9199=B088A00000098100011==00000981000
A88A0A19AA8A9B=B088A00000088900012==00000889000
A88A0A0B380A13=B088A00000099A00013==0000099A000
A88A0A13899A18=B088A00000088A00014==0000088A000
A88A0A1A188910=B088A0000008A800015==000008A8000
A88A0A10930AA0=B088A0000009B900016==000009B9000
A88A0A09338A88=B088A000000A0A00017==00000A0A000
A88A0A11A98930=B088A000000AAB00018==00000AAB000
```

Setting the LPF (lines Per File) to 6, here is the result (first of 3 files):

```
A88A0A1891BAA9                                         
A88A0A1B13A0BB                                          
A88A0A1A13B830                                          
A88A0A00331831                                       
A88A0A10B31B39                               
A88A0A19A3AA89
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second = in the `delims` :

```
For /F "delims=" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks! PROBLEM SOLVED! I think I need some sleep. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

delims== means the command tries to split each line with =

What you need is

```
For /F "tokens=*" %%l in (%BFN%) Do
```

This means "give me the whole line without splitting it into tokens"

Also in your code above the nesting of the do ( ) blocks seems wrong.
It looks like the first for loop simply sets environment variables and does nothing else. Did you actually run this code?

It should be

```
@echo off
FOR %%X IN (*.TXT) do (
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET BFN=%%X
    SET LPF=6000
    SET SFN=%%X_6000_

    REM ==============================
    SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%

    SET /A LineNum=0
    SET /A FileNum=1

    For /F "tokens=*" %%l in (%BFN%) Do
        SET /A LineNum+=1

        echo %%l >> %SFN%!FileNum!.%SFX%

        if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
            SET /A LineNum=0
            SET /A FileNum+=1
        )

    )
endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was was wrong... The problem went undetected for a while because I needed to run only one file at a time...